# Applying CSS to Text inputs with Classes

Tags: html, css, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validate on a form I am building and it is working great. What I want to do is when something is invalid to have the text field change colors and the error message to be white. I figured the following CSS would work:

```
label .error {color: white; font-weight: bold;}
input .error {background-color: pink; border: 1px dashed red; color: white}
```

When I test the validation the above CSS doesn't seem to apply. I checked using Firebug and the label and input area have the 'error' class applied.

The CSS seems valid as when I leave off the .error clause everything looks like I want it too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One space can be one too much. Try:

```
label.error {color: white; font-weight: bold;}
input.error {background-color: pink; border: 1px dashed red; color: white}
```

Background info:

```
label .error  /* selects all elements of class "error" *within* any label */
label.error   /* selects labels of class "error"                          */
```

Comment: Bang. Nailed it. Nice catch, Tomalak!

Answer (score 3):

Try label.error and input.error without spaces.